# Is it possible to open RMI Registry from server code itself

Tags: java, registry, rmi

Is it possible to open rmi registry through java applications which contains the rmi server??
Please suggest a way to implement it from the server code?

Iam actually geting this error

```
The Remote Exception thrown isjava.rmi.ServerException: 
RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
///java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments;
nested exception is: ///java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:    
........xyz(class name).
```

what is the cause and how can it be rectified?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The cause is that the Registry doesn't have that class on its CLASSPATH. Running the Registry in the server JVM will fix it, as per @Dave Webb's answer.

Comment: Iam sorry but i checked the .class file and it is present in the same classpath.Still the problem persists.Can't figure out what's wrong :(

Comment: What is the class name concerned? Specifically, is it a stub file? and if so have you generated it? and deployed it to the client(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an RMI Registry in your server process using [`LocateRegistry.createRegistry()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/rmi/registry/LocateRegistry.html#createRegistry%28int%29).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring's `org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiRegistryFactoryBean` which will either bind to an existing registry or create one if it doesn't find one.